# [0].click() fires once and .click() is firing three times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$('#idElelemnt')[0].click() --> fires once
```

but

```
$('#idElelemnt').click() --> firing three times.
```

there is no `On.('click')` binds, we are using input onclick property.

Also manual click fires once too.

Html

```
<div class="radio radio-success radio-inline ">
    <input type="radio" id="uniqueId" onclick="yesOrNoCheck()" value="someValue">
    <label for="uniqueId">
        text
    </label>
</div>
```

Any clue?

Comment: [0].click() solves the problem, I wanna know the reason why .click() is firing three times.

I already check if multiple script are loaded, if there is multiple id, if there is a bind like .on('click',....), and there is nothing, what am I missing?

Comment: even $('#idElelemnt').first().click() is firing three times, and $("#idElement").length is 1

Comment: there is no attaching out of the tag:
<input type="radio" id="uniqueId" onclick="yesOrNoCheck()" value="someValue">

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the click event by jQuery itself (the proper way to do this), not like onclick:

```
<div class="radio radio-success radio-inline ">
<input type="radio" id="uniqueId" value="someValue">
<label for="uniqueId">
    text
</label>
</div>


<script>
$('#uniqueId').on("click", function(){yesOrNoCheck();})
// programmatic click on element should fire only once:
$('#uniqueId').click();
</script>
```